# Retract spaces- Material or book recomendations

Tags: algebraic-topology, book-recommendation, retraction

Good afternoon to all!

I have just done a course on Algebraic Topology and I came across the definition of a retract space. Not much more is mentioned with regards to the topological retraction property in the notes I was using. I wonder what the best material to understand this concept more in depth is?

Keeping in mind that I do no have an extensive knowledge on Algebraic Topology, but just the knowledge given by an introductory course on the subject.
The definition of such space which I am mentioning here that is presented in the notes is the following:

Let $Y \subset X$ .  A map $ f: X \rightarrow Y$ is called a retraction of $X$ onto $Y$ if $f$ restricted to $Y$ is the identity map on $Y$. Then $Y$ is called a $retract$ of $X$ .

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess the textbook suggested for the course by the professor.

Comment: @Gae.S. There is none which has a focus on retract spaces

Comment: I don't know what a 'retract space' is. There are classic texts like Hu's or Borsuks, on 'The Theory of Retracts', but I very much doubt this is what your professor has in mind in a modern introductory course to algebraic topology.

Comment: @Tyrone thank you for your suggestions! You say you don't think it is what he has in mind, is it because is far beyond the level of understanding of an introductory course to Algebraic topology that you say this? Also I shall add the definition given in the lecture notes.

Comment: Because it belongs to an older branch of (mainly point-set) topology (the books I referenced date from the 1950s). The material does not generally form part of a modern approach to algebraic topology. I suspect that the confusion you are having is something that could probably be cleared up in a couple of paragraphs. Please do include a definition of `retract space' (which I again suspect will contain literally everything you need to know about them).

Comment: @Tyrone I see, so is there a similar concept in modern topology? I have now included the definition in my question!

Answer (score 1):

The 'Theory of Retracts' that I referenced in the books above is a *lot more* involved than this (which is why I doubted your professor would introduce it) . Past a little experience, the definition you give is about as in depth as you will need to understand retracts.

Spelling out your definition, let $i:A\hookrightarrow X$ be a subspace inclusion. Then $A$ is a *retract* of $X$ if there is a map $r:X\rightarrow A$, called a *retraction*, such that

$$r\circ i=id_A.$$

The map $r$ need not be unique. Let $X$ be nonempty. Then the empty set $\emptyset$ is not a retract of $X$. If $x\in X$ is any point, then $\{x\}$ is a retract of $X$. Not every subspace $A\subseteq X$ is a retract. For instance $S^n\subseteq D^{n+1}$ is not a retract (can you prove this using some basic algebraic topology?). If $Y$ is also nonempty, then $X$ is a retract of $X\times Y$ and $X\sqcup Y$. If $A\subseteq X$ is a retract and $X$ is Hausdorff, then $A$ is closed in $X$ (this is an exercise in point-set topology).

There is not much to them theoretically, and they tend to be more useful when recognised in particular examples. The equation $r\circ i=id_A$, through the eyes of an algebraic topologist, is what contains their real power (see the examples above, for instance).